# Scheduler works incorrect in unit testing

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, scheduled-tasks, runnable

I need to collect data from a public API. I want to collect it daily or twice a day.

```java
public class AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcher {
    public static void startAlphavantageStockScraper(int timeInterval) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable getStockList =
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        List<AlphavantageStock> stocks = AlphavantageStockRequest.getStockPrices(); //Method contains requests

                        StockDao<AlphavantageStock> dao = new JpaAlphavantageStockDao();

                        for (AlphavantageStock stock : stocks) {
                            dao.save(stock);
                        }
                    }
                };

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(getStockList, 0, timeInterval, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I start it from the same class (just added main method and invoked `startAlphavantageStockScraper(1);` it works fine. But when I want to test it via JUnit it's not working (test class is in symmetric package name but `test` subfolder):

```java
public class AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcherTest {
    @Test
    public void startDispatcher_TwoFullCycles_WithOneHourIntervalBetween() {
        AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcher.startAlphavantageStockScraper(1);
    }
}
```

While debugging I found out that in unit test execution a program reaches `public void run()` line then skips it. So there's no error. Program ends up correctly but does nothing useful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how asynchronous programming works. In the `AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcher` class you've just submitted a task but you have to wait for it's completed. There are several ways to handle this situation. I prefer state notification using `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`. So some refactoring is recommended in `AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcher` class like this:

```java
public class AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcher {
    public static void startAlphavantageStockScraper(int timeInterval, CountDownLatch latch) {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        Runnable getStockList =
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("worker started");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10_000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            System.out.println("worker finished");
                            Optional.ofNullable(latch).ifPresent(CountDownLatch::countDown);
                        }
                    }
                };

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(getStockList, 0, timeInterval, TimeUnit.HOURS);

    }

}
```

Now it's possible to test that.

```java
public class AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcherTest {

    @Test
    void startDispatcher_TwoFullCycles_WithOneHourIntervalBetween() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        AlphavantageStockRequestDispatcher.startAlphavantageStockScraper(1, latch);
        latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("first finished - need some assertions");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems working. But it's strange that I have to modify method's signature just to unit test it.

Comment: No, you only have to modify method body to track background thread states. It's enough to wait for e.g. 20 seconds in the test method, but I think it is one of the dirtiest way.